# Golang application with Walk compiled but window has not showed

Tags: go, goland

I use Goland v. 2020.1 and compile example appication on https://github.com/lxn/walk
There is three files - main.go, main.manifest , and go.mod in the project.
Project has been compiled and there is message "Process finished with exit code 0"
But there is no window or any result of program.

Comment: To quote from the repo:

`IMPORTANT: If you don't embed a manifest as a resource, then you should not launch your executable before the manifest file is in place. If you do anyway, the program will not run properly. And worse, Windows will not recognize a manifest file, you later drop next to the executable. To fix this, rebuild your executable and only launch it with a manifest file in place.`
Have you embedded the resource file or copied it to the output with the correct name?